# Windows XP on domain: Is it possible to create a user profile directory prior to user logging onto computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote, domain, user-profile

I'm prepping a couple workstations that will replace older systems in a remote office that does not have local IT staff. Users will connect the new computers in place of the old computers when they receive them, and log in using their domain credentials.

There is not an easy way to have the local staff connect the new computers in addition to the old computers due to limited space and computer accessories (monitors, keyboards, mice) and network connections.

So what I am doing is copying the information from the primary user for each old computer onto the new computer into a directory all Domain Users have everything except Full Control of prior to shipping it with instructions that the users be very careful to save all new files between now and when they receive the new computers onto the network.

THE QUESTION: Is there a way to create the user profile directories (C:\Documents and Settings\... prior to the user logging in to the computer for the first time such that Windows will accept this as the user directory when the user does log in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  When creating a profile Windows will search the contents of `c:\documents and settings\` and if it finds a folder with the name it wants to create, it will create a different folder instead.

About your best bet as an alternative would be to use roaming profiles.

Comment: Roaming profiles isn't on our domain. Thanks for the answer. I was pretty sure this was the case, but it's good to know with a little more certainty.